# Trying to print factors of a number within a list using two functions

Tags: python

The printing output I'm getting contains the list that I want, but also the word `None` for some reason. I have a function defined as `factors` and my main function that is trying to print the factors of a specified number. Like I said, my output is:

```
[1, 17]
None
```

This is what my current code looks like and everything is indented, but stack overflow wont let me copy it over cleanly:

```
def factors(myNumber):
    fact = []
    for i in range(1, myNumber + 1):
        if myNumber % i == 0:
            fact.append(i)
    print(fact)

def main():
    print(factors(17))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: That's because you `print` the output of `factors(17)`, but that functions does not `return` any value, only prints `fact`. You may want to use `return fact` at the end of your `factors` function.

Comment: four space before the code indent it, there is also button in the editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome @IcyG. The output you're seeing happens because you `print` the output of `factors(17)`, but that functions does not `return` any value, only prints `fact`. When you do not include a `return` statement in a function, it returns `None`, which is why your second output is a `None`. You may want to use `return fact` at the end of your `factors` function:

```
def factors(myNumber):
    fact = []
    for i in range(1, myNumber + 1):
        if myNumber % i == 0:
            fact.append(i)
    return fact

def main():
    result = factors(17)  # Added to explicitly show that this returns a value
    print(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: So return allows me to return values to my predefined list which makes printing possible through a different function?

Comment: The `return` statement defines the value that your function will return, exactly. That's why you can pass the value calculated inside `factors` to another function (`main`) .

Answer (score 0):

Your `factors` function returns `None`, and you are printing it, this is why

Answer (score 0):

As others have already explained, your first function returns `None` (which is the default return value, if a value is not provided). The following code is equivalent to yours and hopefully makes it more clear:

```
def factors(myNumber):
    fact = []
    for i in range(1, myNumber + 1):
        if myNumber % i == 0:
            fact.append(i)
    print(fact)
    return None

def main():
    result = factors(17)
    print(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```